# Declaration of multiple arrays on a single line in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I've wasted two hours of my life on the declaration of an array. I know how to avoid the problem now, but I want to understand what goes wrong here. I'm new again at VBA and I want to understand what i'm doing rather than just doing random edits until it works... which is what I did here!

This first code works:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim X(3) As Double
    Dim V(3) As Double
    Call SimpleFunc(X)
    Debug.Print "Finished!"
End Sub

Private Sub Func1(ByRef X() As Double)
    X(1) = 0.1
    X(2) = 0.2
    X(3) = 0.3
End Sub
```

But this second code doesn't (error at compile "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"). The only difference is in the declaration of X and V.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim X(3), V(3) As Double
    Call SimpleFunc(X)
    Debug.Print "Finished!"
End Sub

Private Sub Func1(ByRef X() As Double)
    X(1) = 0.1
    X(2) = 0.2
    X(3) = 0.3
End Sub
```

Why is X not an array in this latter code?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to specify the data type for each variable if you insist on declaring multiples on one line:

```
Dim X(3) As Double, V(3) As Double
```

If you don't specify a data type, VBA assumes the type is `Variant`. A `Variant` can be an `Array`, but then you shouldn't use the array notation:

```
Dim V(3) As Double
Dim X

X = V ' X is now an array
```

Comment: Oh a variant type... Is it only for arrays though? Because I have found this on the microsoft visual basic page: >> Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer << with the comment >> 'a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double << and I've been using such a syntax throughout my code. Was I defining Variants?

Comment: @Godzy: I think you were.

Comment: Those examples may have been for .NET  You have to be careful when checking the MS site otherwise it's easy to end up rwading the wrong docs...

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify both types, logically I used to think it would work as you have it but it doesn't.

Do this:

```
Dim X(3) As Double, V(3) As Double
```

The benefit though is you don't have to group types, you could have something like:

```
Dim X as long, Y as Double, V as Variant, Z(3) as String
```

All on one line